# Whatsappwebjs heroku with RemoteAuth is not working

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer, whatsapp

I am trying to use the RemoteAuth option in WhatsAppWebJS, and it works perfectly fine on my local machine. However, when it comes to deploying it on Heroku, I encounter an issue. The QR code is displayed, but it's impossible to see in the Heroku console due to unknown '   ' symbols. So, I retrieve the string version of the QR code, recreate it as a QR code image, and then scan it to open the session.

The problem is that when I scan it on Heroku, nothing happens. There's no new QR code displayed, and there are no error messages. I fixed a problematic line in the 'Client.js' file (changed 'const INTRO_IMG_SELECTOR = 'div[role='textbox']';' to //'[data-icon='chat']';), and this fixed the issue locally, but it doesn't work on the Heroku server. Can anyone explain why this might be happening?

```
const { Client, RemoteAuth} = require("whatsapp-web.js");
const qrcode = require("qrcode-terminal");

const { MongoStore } = require("wwebjs-mongo");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('dotenv').config();

const mongoURI = process.env.DB_URL;

mongoose
.connect(`${mongoURI}/message`, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
})
.then(() => {
  console.log("MongoDB Connected to messageService.js");
  const store = new MongoStore({ mongoose: mongoose });
  const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new RemoteAuth({
      store: store,
      backupSyncIntervalMs: 120000,
    }),  puppeteer: {
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', "--disable-setuid-sandbox"]
    },
  });

  client.on("qr", async (qr) => {
    console.log(qr)
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
  });

  client.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log("Client is ready!")
    
    const number = "+90*****0171";
    const chatId = number.substring(1) + "@c.us";
    await client.sendMessage(chatId, "SERVER IS READY");

  });

  client.on("remote_session_saved", () => {
    console.log("remote_session_saved");
  });

  client.initialize();
  module.exports = client;
});
```

Also about webpacks. I am using "heroku/nodejs" and "https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer.tgz"

I was expecting it to execute

```
console.log("Client is ready!")
```

and after a minute

```
console.log("remote_session_saved");
```